# Gráfico não está saindo no output

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Funcao Poder"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("n1",
                  "Tamanho da amostra:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      sliderInput("n2",
                  "Tamanho da amostra:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      sliderInput("n3",
                  "Tamanho da amostra:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      sliderInput("n4",
                  "Tamanho da amostra:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("p1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p1 <- renderPlot({
    poder.media = function(n,mu){
      k = qnorm(1-0.05,50,sqrt(25/n))
      prob = 1 - pnorm(k, mu, sqrt(25/n))
      return(prob)
    }
    n <- input$n1
    curve(poder.media(n,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",add=TRUE,col="red")
    nn <- input$n2
    curve(poder.media(nn,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",add=TRUE,col="blue")
    nnn <- input$n3
    curve(poder.media(nnn,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",add=TRUE,col="green")
    nnnn <- input$n4
    curve(poder.media(nnnn,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",add=TRUE,col="yellow")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Gostaria de gerar uma aplicação q para cada `n` alterado no input seja gerado um curve com a função colocada no server (a função está no local certo?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na linha

```
curve(poder.media(n,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",add=TRUE,col="red")
```

Ao colocar o argumento `add=TRUE`, o `R` é informado que ele precisa adicionar o resultado desta curva a um gráfico que já foi plotado. Mas, até o momento, não existe nenhum gráfico na tua aplicação. Substitua esta linha, que possui o código do primeiro gráfico a ser plotado, pela linha abaixo:

```
curve(poder.media(n,x),40,60,xlab=expression(mu),ylab = "Poder",col="red")
```

A única diferença entre elas é a exclusão do argumento `add=TRUE`. Fazendo isso, o resultado é a tela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda